# pandas value_counts() with IntEnum raises RecursionError

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I got the following code to elaborate on my problem. I'm using python 3.6 with pandas==0.25.3.

```
import pandas as pd
from enum import Enum, IntEnum


class BookType(Enum):
  DRAMA = 5
  ROMAN = 3


class AuthorType(IntEnum):
  UNKNOWN = 0
  GROUP = 1
  MAN = 2


def print_num_type(df: pd.DataFrame, col_name: str, enum_type: Enum) -> int:
    counts = df[col_name].value_counts()
    val = counts[enum_type]
    print('value counts:', counts)
    print(f'Found "{val}" of type {enum_type}')


d = {'title': ['Charly Morry', 'James', 'Watson', 'Marry L.'], 'isbn': [21412412, 334764712, 12471021, 124141111], 'book_type': [BookType.DRAMA, BookType.ROMAN, BookType.ROMAN, BookType.ROMAN], 'author_type': [AuthorType.UNKNOWN, AuthorType.UNKNOWN, AuthorType.MAN, AuthorType.UNKNOWN]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.set_index(['title', 'isbn'], inplace=True)
df['book_type'] = df['book_type'].astype('category')
df['author_type'] = df['author_type'].astype('category')

print(df)
print(df.dtypes)

print_num_type(df, 'book_type', BookType.DRAMA)
print_num_type(df, 'author_type', AuthorType.UNKNOWN)
```

My `pandas.DataFrame` consists of two columns (`book_type` and `author_type`) of type `categorical`.
Furthermore, `book_type` is a class inheriting from type `Enum` and `author_type` from `IntEnum`. When calling `print_num_type(df, 'book_type', BookType.DRAMA)` everything works out as expected and the number of books of this type are printed, whereas `print_num_type(df, 'author_type', AuthorType.UNKNOWN)` raises the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\abc.py", line 182, in __instancecheck__
    if subclass in cls._abc_cache:
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\_weakrefset.py", line 72, in __contains__
    wr = ref(item)
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
Exception ignored in: 'pandas._libs.lib.c_is_list_like'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\abc.py", line 182, in __instancecheck__
    if subclass in cls._abc_cache:
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\_weakrefset.py", line 72, in __contains__
    wr = ref(item)
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

What am I doing wrong here?
Is there a workaround to get this error fixed? since I can't change the `IntEnum` type of `AuthorType` since it's provided from another library.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here is a minimal working example of this error: 
    x = pd.Series([1,0]).astype('category')
    x.value_counts()[0] ## produces recursion error. 
interestingly, ` x.value_counts()[1]` returns 1.

Answer (score 0):

See answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60428707/maximum-recursion-depth-exceeded-when-summarizing-a-categorical-variable)

The main idea is that since `x.value_counts()` or `counts` in your function is itself a pandas Series, it's best to use `.iat` or `.iloc` when calling it, e.g, [see iat docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.at.html)

I think the easiest solution is to just use `(x==0).sum()`, or in your syntax:

```
val = (df[col_name]==enum_type).sum()
```

I put a minimal working example in the comments under your question so you can reproduce the problem/fix easily with the "x" notation.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Pandas are you using? I realized after reproducing the error that upgrading Pandas (now on pandas-1.4.2) fixes the error, and the `value_counts()[0]` worked as expected.

run `pip install --upgrade pandas`