# maximum recursion depth exceeded when summarizing a categorical variable

Tags: python, pandas, recursion, categorical-data, depth

When trying to get the counts for each level of a pandas series category I get a 'maximum recursion depth exceeded' error

A code example that produce the error is as follows:

```
vs = pd.Series([0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1]).astype('category')
tn = pd.Series.value_counts(vs)
print(tn[0])
print(tn[1])
```

The part that generated the error is the call to tn[0]. Calling tn[1] does not give such error.
If I add more levels I can call the next levels but tn[0] always return error.
What is wrong with this code?
I'm using Python 3.7.4 and Pandas 0.25.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
vs = pd.Series([0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1]).astype('category')
tn = vs.value_counts()
print(tn)
1    5
0    3
dtype: int64

print(tn[pd.Categorical(0)])
1    5
dtype: int64

print(tn[pd.Categorical(1)])
0    3
dtype: int64
```

For select by positions use [`Series.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iloc.html) or [`Series.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iat.html):

```
print(tn.iloc[0])
5
print(tn.iloc[1])
3
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what if I need to reference the 'tn' variable by its index?

Comment: @tomkarp - Not understand, can you explian more?

Comment: I need to access each of the counts in the order they appear in the tn variable and not by their category level. When you print the tn you have that level 1 appears 5 times (so it is in position 0 -> tn[0]) while level 0 appears only 3 times (tn[1]). When I print tn[1] I get the count for level 0, but tn[0] returns error.

Comment: @tomkarp - Do you need `print(tn.iloc[0])

print(tn.iloc[1])` ?  [`Series.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iloc.html) ?

Comment: Upps, I got it. Thank you @jezrael :-)